# "Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred." - Attempting to draw a rectangle using openGL on android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

This is roughly my second time diving into working with openGL on android and I can't seem to even decipher these two odd error messages:

```
E/InputDispatcher(60): channel '407a76f8 root.AirGates/root.AirGates.AirGatesActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
E/InputDispatcher(60): channel '407a76f8 root.AirGates/root.AirGates.AirGatesActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

I've tried to separate out all of my openGL code below:

#### Setting up the viewport:

```
GL10 graphics = glGraphics.getGlGraphics();

graphics.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1);
graphics.glViewport(0, 0, glGraphics.getWidth(), glGraphics.getHeight());

graphics.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
graphics.glLoadIdentity();

graphics.glOrthof(0, glGraphics.getWidth(), 0, glGraphics.getHeight(), 1, -1);
```

#### Before I render (setting the vertex indexing and values):

```
// allocate a 'raw' byte buffer, then 'cast it' into a ShortBuffer a short has 2 bytes of memory and there are 6 values
// (6 values because 2 tris with 3 vertices each, make up a quad)
// 0---1
// | / |
// 3---2
ByteBuffer tempBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(6 * 2);
tempBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
vertexNumIndexes = tempBuffer.asShortBuffer();
vertexNumIndexes.put(new short[]{0,1,3, 1,2,3});
vertexNumIndexes.flip();

// need to allocate memory to hold the vertices: float is 4 bytes, times 4 vertices, times 2 (each vertex has an x and y)
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * 2 * 4);
byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
vertices = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
Point temp;
for(int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++){
    temp = gate.getPoint(counter);
    vertices.put(temp.x);
    vertices.put(temp.y);
}
vertices.flip();

// values in 'vertices' are:
// 140.18016, 387.5
// 339.81982, 387.5
// 339.81982, 412.5
// 140.18016, 412.5
```

#### In my actual render() method call:

```
GL10 graphics = glGraphics.getGlGraphics();

// set colour, RGBA
graphics.glColor4f(1, 1, 0, 1);

graphics.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
graphics.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
graphics.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, vertexNumIndexes);
graphics.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

My app pops up, goes full screen black (as set up by the viewport), then exits. Any idea what it could mean? I am trying to draw a simple red rectangle (made up of the 2 triangles) at the moment.

Comment: check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437039/opengl-random-crash-on-honeycomb-with-hardware-accelerated-param-set-to-true

Comment: Hi, I've checked a few other questions on here that mentioned the same error, but they all seem to be about different things (another mentioned screen orientation as well), which was why I posted my question. I have no hardware acceleration set and memory-wise I think the only time I have that set is when I am dealing with the bytebuffers (?) and I've checked them. Or perhaps you're trying to get at something else from that question? I should have added I am writing against the 2.2/2.3 api.